# Validation for blank characters? Angular 4

Tags: angular, validation

I need to create some kind of validation on my forms where I don't want user to be able to enter 1++ blank spaces inside fields. So, he can type space but it cannot be only spaces. This is how my validation looks like at the moment:

```
this.valForm = this.fb.group({
      'firstName': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])],
      'lastName': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])]
});
```

I dont know what pattern to use to create this type of validation. Thanks.

Comment: user is allowed to enter only one white spaces right ?

Comment: @ArunKumaresh User can enter spaces but it cannot be only spaces inside field, so it can be 'Example Valu e ' , but it cannot be ' ' , '       ' , something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a custom validator which checks for

```
userInputString.trim() !== ''
```

A validator is not much more than a function which takes a control and returns whether it is valid or not (either as a boolean or a promise/observable).

For more details check out any example out there for custom validators in angular 2+, e.g.

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Wouldn't this .indexOf(' ') check for any space inside the field?

Comment: Oh sorry i missunderstood your question, hang on, i'll adjust my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
'firstName': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.pattern(/^((?!\s{2,}).)*$/)]]
```

If you test it on [Scriptular](http://scriptular.com/) with the chain `^((?!\s{2,}).)*$`, you will find that

```
Hello darling // Matches
Hello  darling // Doesn't match
```

This isn't something regexes should do : they're not good at it. A regex is supposed to find an occurence of your expression in a string, not the opposite. But still, they can do it.

If you want to know more, this is called a **negative look-around**.